# Unable to make install Gromacs on Cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I'm wondering if anyone could help me. I've been compiling GROMACS in Windows using CYGWIN and this tutorial - http://megaddl.pcriot.com/installing-gromacs-5-1-1-in-windows-using-cygwin/

However, when I go to make install, I get the following output:

```
$ make install
[  0%] Built target fftwBuild
[  0%] Built target tng_io_zlib
[  1%] Built target tng_io_obj
[ 98%] Built target libgromacs
[100%] Built target template
[100%] Built target view_objlib
[100%] Built target mdrun_objlib
[100%] Built target gmx
[100%] Built target mdrun_test_objlib
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/gromacs/share/gromacs/COPYING
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot set permissions on
  "/usr/local/gromacs/share/gromacs/COPYING"
```

Any idea what I should do to rectify this?

Comment: what is the output of  `getfacl /usr/local/gromacs/share/gromacs/COPYING` ?

Comment: `$ getfacl /usr/local/gromacs/share/gromacs/COPYING'`    
`# file: /usr/local/gromacs/share/gromacs/COPYING`    
`# owner: llwgroup`    
`# group: Domain Users`
`user::r--`

Comment: 5.1.1 - released November 9, 2015 http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/ .... Usually it's a good idea to try out some later versions : 2016.2, -.3, -4, -5 and  2018, 2018.1 . Not easy to tell which version can be built with an unknown Windows© version / Cygwin version.